Kotlin to LLVM IR .ll
Hello! I have been exploring the LLVM .ll  libraries and as Kotlin is a LLVM language, I assumed that I could compile to IR. However, I couldn't find any documentation on how to do that. Even ChatGPT suggests that there is no option for it.
Since LLVM is all about IR and the strength of using different languages in the same project with a shared IR base, I am wondering if JetBrains intentionally left out that option or if I simply don't understand the documentation and it is there in plain sight.

Q: Does anybody know how?

Also, I am curious if I can use IR .ll class files in my Kotlin code, from Rust, Clang or Swift .ll's.

Q: How do I do that?

Thank you!
-LPM, new to Kotlin
I tried to go through the kotlinc-native help and the online docs. None seemed to allow for IR compilation but went directly to byte code.

"LLVM is all about IR and the strength of using different languages in the same project with a shared IR base"? That doesn't match my understanding.
Rather, the point of LLVM is to cooperate in the way  compilers need. All compilers need the same kind of constant folding and the same kind of ARM code generation, so LLVM does that in one way (more or less). But languages/compilers don't need the same kind of parameter passing when calling functions, or the same memory layout, or the same exception mechanism, or the same polymorphism, so for those, LLVM just provides tools to let each compiler do what it needs, without trying to do it in the same way.
This makes LLVM very valuable for compiler authors, but 97% useless for people who want to use several languages in the same project.
